# Is there continuous $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that for all $x$ there is $y$ with $f(y) < f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, transfinite-recursion

I think there isn't. Here's a sketch of a proof. I'm just not sure whether it really works because I'm not confident with the transfinite versions of the standard theorems about limits and convergent sequences.

Attempted proof: Suppose there were such a function. Then use transfinite recursion to generate the following transfinite sequence:

BASE CASE: $s_0 = 1$.

SUCCESSOR ORDINAL: Let $s_{\lambda + 1}$ be a number in $[0, 1]$ such that $f(s_{\lambda + 1}) < f(s_\lambda)$.

LIMIT ORDINAL: Suppose $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal. Then the sequence $f(s_0)$, ..., $f(s_\alpha)$, ... with $\alpha < \lambda$ is bounded below by 0. So it has a limit $\lim_{\alpha < \lambda} f(s_\alpha$) (by a transfinite version of the Monotone Convergence Theorem). Also (by a transfinite version of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem) there is a subsequence of $s_0$, ..., $s_\alpha$, ... that is unbounded in that sequence and it converges to a limit. Let's call that subsequence $s_{i_0}$, ..., $s_{i_\beta}, ...$ for $\beta < \gamma \leq \lambda$. Then let
$s := \lim_{\beta < \gamma} s_{i_\beta}$
Then, since $f$ is continuous,
$$
\lim_{\alpha < \lambda} f(s_\alpha) = \lim_{\beta < \gamma} f(s_{i_\beta}) = f(s)
$$
So let $s_\lambda = s = \lim_{\beta < \gamma} s_{i_\beta}$.

Then there must be $\alpha$ such that $s_\alpha = s_{\alpha + 1}$, since there are at most continuum-many distinct numbers in the list $f(s_0)$, ..., $f(s_\alpha)$, ... . This gives a contradiction.

Comment: There is no reason to go to transfinite induction. This theorem is much easier to prove if you know the notion of "compact space" and a few theorems about compact spaces.

Comment: Also, there is no such $f$ even if you allow $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$, and then your argument using Monotone Convergence is going to fail.

Comment: Some (complicated) transfinite induction argument might be necessary if you want to eliminate the continuity assumption on $f$.

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro: The statement is wrong if the continuity assumption is dropped

Answer (score 8):

There is a rather simple proof using basic analysis: A continuous function $f$ on the  compact interval $[0,1]$ is always bounded and attains its minimum [(Extreme value theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). If $x \in [0,1]$ is such that $f(x) = \inf_{[0,1]} f$, then there would be no $y$ with $f(y) < f(x)$.

Proof of the existence of a minimum: Let $M=\inf_{[0,1]} f$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact there is a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$. You can show this using the Bolzano-Weierstraß-Theorem. Let $x = \lim_k x_{n_k}$, then $f(x) = \lim_k f(x_{n_k}) = \lim_n f(x_n) = M$.

I don't know about your limit ordinal proof, but using transfinite methods and thereby the axiom of choice is not necessary for this proof.